# Logging Into Google To Scrape A Private Google Group (over HTTPS)

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to log into Google, so that I can scrape & migrate a private google group.

It doesn't seem to log in over SSL. Any ideas appreciated. I'm using Mechanize and the code is below:

```
group_signin_url = "https://login page to goolge, with referrer url to a private group here"

user = ENV['GOOGLE_USER']
password = ENV['GOOGLE_PASSWORD']

scraper = Mechanize.new
scraper.user_agent = Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES["Linux Firefox"]
scraper.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

page = scraper.get group_signin_url
google_form = page.form 
google_form.Email = user
google_form.Passwd = password

group_page = scraper.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)
pp group_page
```

Comment: You can't get there using one of their APIs? Try turning off JavaScript in your browser, and see what information is available on that page. That is what Mechanize will see *IF* it can get that far.

Comment: Sadly not. There's not API coverage for this.

Comment: The answer to this turned out to be use Selenium. When it's fully working I'll post a link to the git repo. Should prove useful for all of those wanting to migrate from Google Groups, but especially to discourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with Ian (the OP) on this problem and just felt we should close this thread with some answers based on what we found when we spent some more time on the problem.

1) You can't scrape a Google Group with Mechanize. We managed to get logged in abut the content of the Google Group pages is all rendered **in-browser**, meaning that HTTP requests, such as issued by Mechanize, are returned with a few links and no actual content.

We found that we could get page content by the use of Selenium (we used Selenium in Firefox, using the Ruby bindings).

2) the HTML element IDs/classes in Google Groups are obfuscated but we found that these Selenium commands will pull out the bits you need (until Google change them)

#### message snippets (click on them to expand messages)

`find_elements(:class, 'GFP-UI5CCLB')`

#### elements with name of author

`find_elements(:class, 'GFP-UI5CA1B')`

#### elements with content of post

`find_elements(:class, 'GFP-UI5CCKB')`

#### elements containing date

`find_elements(:class, 'GFP-UI5CDKB')` (and then use the attribute[:title] for a full length date string)

3) I have some Ruby code [here](https://github.com/pacharanero/google_group.to_discourse) which scrapes the content programmatically and uploads it into a Discourse forum (which is what we were trying to migrate to).

It's hacky but it kind of works. I recently migrated 2 commercially important Google Groups using this script. I'm up for taking on 'We Scrape Your Google Group' type work, please PM me.